# TypeError: Expected input type is Uint8Array (got object)

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ethereum, truffle, jsdom

I am trying to make a frontend application in which I'm using jest for testing the frontend layers.
For the same, I want to get the provider from the HDWalletProviderFactory here but when I try to do this `public provider = HDWalletProviderFactory.getProvider(Chain.ethereum())`[here Chain.ethereum() is a value object], I get this error :

```
    TypeError: Expected input type is Uint8Array (got object)

       18 |         }
    > 19 |         return new HDWalletProvider({
         |                ^
      20 |             mnemonic: {
      21 |                 phrase: Env.get('OPERATION_MNEMONIC')
      22 |             },

      at toBytes (node_modules/@noble/hashes/utils.js:89:15)
      at pbkdf2Init (node_modules/@noble/hashes/pbkdf2.js:17:45)
      at pbkdf2 (node_modules/@noble/hashes/pbkdf2.js:42:44)
      at mnemonicToSeedSync (node_modules/@scure/bip39/index.js:140:32)
      at HDWalletProvider.checkBIP39Mnemonic (node_modules/@truffle/hdwallet-provider/src/index.ts:329:25)
      at new HDWalletProvider (node_modules/@truffle/hdwallet-provider/src/index.ts:109:12)
      at Function.getProvider (tests/data/reusable_classes/hd_wallet_provider_factory.ts:20:23)
      at AuthorizationInitializer.getProvider (tests/data/reusable_classes/authorization_token.ts:22:47)
      at new AuthorizationInitializer (tests/data/reusable_classes/authorization_token.ts:15:16)
```

I want to solve it but I'm not able to understand this error.
Can someone help me with this Please?

For reference I am also attaching the HDWalletProviderFactory code here where the error is being generated.

```
.
.
.

export default class HDWalletProviderFactory {

    public static getProvider(chain:Chain): HDWalletProvider {

        return new HDWalletProvider({
            mnemonic: {
                phrase: Env.get('OPERATION_MNEMONIC')
            },
            providerOrUrl: Env.get('ETHEREUM_HDWALLET_PROVIDER_URL')
        })
    }
}
```